# How do I map enums to String resources?

Tags: java, android, enums

I have a list of enum type `Pet`.

```
enum Pet
{
   DOG, CAT, BIRD, FISH;
}
```

I then load a list of available pets at the store, which end up in a `List`

```
List<Pet> availablePets;
```

The amount of pets will vary. So sometimes the store will have `DOG` and `CAT` other times it will have all the Pets.

The problem is that I have to display a list of the Pets. So I have to display the pet types using String resources because of different languages.

```
public void display()
{
    CharSequence[] list = new CharSequence[availablePets.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < availablePets.size(); i++)
    {
        Pet pet = availablePets.get(i);
        if(pet == Pet.DOG)
        {
            list[i] = getString(R.string.dog);
        }
        else if(pet == Pet.CAT)
        {
            list[i] = getString(R.string.cat);
        }
        ...
    }

    // takes a CharSequence array
    callUi(list);
}
```

My problem is that this does not scale. The moment a new pet comes in then I have to modify a ton of code just to display it.

So how do I print this list of enums using String resources?

Comment: Enums are not recommended for Android as they occupy double the space of the integral constants. And you are using them in list which will worsen your apps memory consumption.

Comment: **new pets come in** - how will you add new pets? through server or for every addition your app will update in playstore?

Comment: I am aware. But I cannot put annotations in a List. Is there a trick besides using `Integer`.

Comment: can you answer my second question too?

Comment: So tomorrow I want to add reptiles then I will change the enum. Ideally that's the only place I will modify.

Comment: That means there is no server interaction? every time you add a pet, you will provide a new update on playstore? just for a pet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R.string.xxx values are actually integers, which are then used by getString() to lookup the appropriate string to display. So the problem you need to solve is how to map your enum values (DOG, CAT etc) to the appropriate integers.

There are a couple of ways to do this:

### - Create a Map which maps them, and then lookup the appropriate integer to pass to getString when you need to display it:

```
Map<Pet, Integer> petTypeToNameMapping = new HashMap<>();
petTypeToNameMapping.put(Pet.DOG, R.string.dog);
...

list[i] = getString(petTypeToNameMapping.get(pet));
```

### - Embed the string resource ids in the Pet enum itself (you can give an enum member variables and a constructor, like a regular class, when you want to associate some additional information with each enum value):

```
enum Pet {
    DOG(R.string.dog), CAT(R.string.cat);

    int nameResourceId;
    Pet(int nameResourceId) {
        this.nameResourceId = nameResourceId;
    }
}

...

list[i] = getString(pet.nameResourceId);
```

Comment: just for your info, both hashmaps and enums are not recommended for Android.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that using a hashmap *with an enum key* is not recommended for Android?

Comment: using hashmaps or enum together or individually too is not recommended.

Comment: Can you explain or give a source for why any use of a hashmap or enum is not recommended? I can see some arguments for using SparseArray etc in certain situations, but it seems odd to have such a broad recommendeation against them

Comment: please read this completely. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html - i cant get more official source than this.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like there is an overhead, although probably a fairly negligible one in many practical situations. I agree that ideally we should use more efficient constructions where possible. But I think that in a case like this (answering what is ultimately a basic Java programming question) it may be appropriate to just note the recommendation and move on.

Comment: trust me. I spent 4 days of my development time in just fixing OOM issue. it looks silly at the beginning. but as you scale your app, these overheads sums up giving rise to OOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138583/discussion-between-caw-and-mohammed-atif).